# react-router-dom link works in app.js(parent component) but doesn't work in child component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I have 'Nav' component in 'app.js' ( parent component ) and 'home.js' conditionally to have white space responsively on the bottom of the header only in Homepage by setting `header { height: 90vh }`.

In order to do that, I included < Nav > in header tag in 'Home.js'.

And Here the problem came up, 
**Nav Link works well in app.js, but it's not even clickable in home.js.**

[Homepage Header Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWoKw.png)

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { ConnectedRouter as Router } from 'react-router-redux';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import Store from './Store';
import Routes from './Routes';

require('./styles/main.scss');

const root = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(root);

render(
  <Provider store={Store}>
    <Router history={createHistory()}>
      <Routes />
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  root,
);
```

**Routes.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { hot } from 'react-hot-loader';
import App from './src/app';
/* --- Components --- */
import Loader from './src/shared/loader';

const Home = Loader({
      loader: () => import('./src/components/Home' /* webpackChunkName: 'Home' */),
    });

const Login = Loader({
      loader: () => import('./src/components/login' /* webpackChunkName: 'Login' */),
    });

const NoMatch = Loader({
      loader: () => import('./src/shared/NoMatch' /* webpackChunkName: 'NoMatch' */),
    });

const routes = () => (
      <div>
        <App />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route component={NoMatch} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );

const Routes =
      !module.hot || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
        ? routes
        : hot(module)(routes);

export default Routes;
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
/* --- shared --- */
import Loader from './shared/loader';

const Nav = Loader({
  loader: () => import('./shared/nav' /* webpackChunkName: 'Nav' */),
});

const App = props => {
  const isHomepage = window.location.pathname === '/';

  return (
    <div id="app">
      <Helmet>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <title>###</title>
        <meta property="og:title" content="###" />
        <meta property="og:description" content="###" />
        <meta property="og:type" content="###" />
        <meta property="og:url" content="###" />
        <meta property="og:image" content="###" />
        <link type="text/plain" rel="author" href="http://domain/humans.txt" />
        <link type="text/plain" rel="author" href="http://domain/robots.txt" />
        <link
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nanum+Gothic"
          rel="stylesheet"
        />
        <link
          rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500"
        />
      </Helmet>
      {props.children}
      {!isHomepage ? <Nav /> : null}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**nav.js**

```
import React from 'react';
/* --- shared --- */
import * as data from './data';
import Ul from './ul';

const Nav = () => (
  <div className="nav">
    <div className="flex justify-between nav--top">
      <p className="mh-auto f-mini fw3">
        상담전화
        <span className="f-regular"> xxx&#45;xxxx&#45;xxxx</span>
      </p>
      <Ul links={data.redirectToLogin} />
    </div>
    <h1>
      <Ul links={data.redirectToHome} />
    </h1>
    <div className="hr-center">
      <Ul links={data.nav} />
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default Nav;
```

**ul.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Ul = ({ links }) => (
  <ul className="nav-menu">
    {links &&
      links.map(e => (
        <li>
          <Link className={e.className} key={e.id} to={e.to}>
            {e.name}
          </Link>
        </li>
      ))}
  </ul>
);

export default Ul;
```

**Home.js**

```
import React from 'react';
/* --- Components --- */
import HomeMain from './Home.main';
/* --- Shared --- */
import Nav from '../shared/nav';

const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <header>
      <Nav />
      <div className="header-text--box">
        <h2>
          <span className="f-regular f-en lh-3">NO MSG!</span>
          <br />
          오늘도 열심히 일하는 당신에게 착한 가격의 집밥을 선물하세요.
        </h2>
      </div>
    </header>
    <HomeMain />
  </div>
);

export default Home;
```

**Version**

```
react: 16.4.2 
react-dom: 16.4.2 
react-redux: 5.0.7 
react-router-dom: 4.3.1 
react-router-redux: 5.0.0-alpha.9
```

Thank you for taking your time to help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your styling, it seems the `header` [has a negative `z-index`](https://github.com/Jin827/yuch/blob/a5654d6ae5aa771ba6ac13c1b4c5fe1876020f1a/client/styles/components/header.scss#L8).

By setting a negative z-index, this is likely to interfere with children of the `<header>` (ie your `<nav>` component), from receiving click events and/or responding to the cursor correctly.

I would recommend removing `z-index: -1;` from your `header.scss` to address your problem. Hope that helps!

Comment: Glad I could help :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'll make a simplified example here of setup that I normally use. So, what about this approach?

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App';
import Provider from "react-redux/es/components/Provider";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from '../reducers/rootReducer';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

// Usually I would do this in an external file, but here I'm configuring my store

const myStore = configureStore(initialState) {
  return createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
  );
}    

// After that, I'm wrapping my App component inside of the Provider and passing in the configured store

ReactDOM.render((
    <Provider store={myStore }>
        <App/>
    </Provider>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

---

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import PrimaryLayoutContainerComponent from "../containers/PrimaryLayoutContainer";

// In my App.js I'm wrapping my primary layout container with BrowserRouter to get access to the history and also passing in the props

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <PrimaryLayoutContainerComponent {...this.props}/>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```

---

**PrimaryLayoutContainerComponent.js**
In this (main container) I would take the full advantage of my previous configs as well as whatever is offered and needed regarding the Redux state management. I also use withRouter at this stage to get access to the history object's properties.

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import * as myActions from '../actions';
import PrimaryLayout from "../components/layout/PrimaryLayout";
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';


class PrimaryLayoutContainerComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                 //Here we pass our history as props
                <PrimaryLayout  history={this.props.history} 
                                propsX={this.props.propsX}

                                propsY={this.props.actions.propsY}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

// In these (and all other cases) I would highly recommend using propTypes.
// They could give you the answer in where the issues might be in your future development 

PrimaryLayoutContainerComponent.propTypes = {
    loggedUser: PropTypes.string,
    actions: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return { xxxx }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(myActions, dispatch)
    };
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PrimaryLayoutContainerComponent));
```

---

...and then finally in my ***`Primary Layout Component`*** I would define all my routes like this:

**PrimaryLayoutComponent.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, Redirect, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
// ... import all my compoenents


class PrimaryLayout extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            currentRoute: '' // I would use the state to dynamically change the  
                             // routes depending on which one was clicked
        }
    }



    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({
            currentRoute: nextProps.history.location.pathname
        })
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.setState({
            currentRoute: this.props.history.location.pathname
        })
    }

    render() {

        const { currentRoute } = this.state;

        return (
            <div className="wrapper">
                <header className="xxxx" role="banner">
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="xxxxx">


                           <Link to="/home">
                             <img src={logo} alt="your logo"/> Your App Name
                           </Link>
                            <ul className="navbar__menu">
                                    <li className={currentRoute === "/home" ? "active" : ""}>
                                        <Link to="/home"> Home </Link>
                                    </li>

                                    <li className={currentRoute === "/componentOne" ? "active" : ""}>
                                        <Link to="/componentOne"> componentOne</Link>
                                    </li>

                                    <li className={currentRoute === "/componentTwo" ? "active" : ""}>
                                        <Link to="/componentTwo"> componentTwo</Link>
                                    </li>
                            </ul>

                        </div>
                    </div>
              </header>

// At the very end, I'm using the Switch HOC and defining my routes inside of a main tag

               <main>
                <Switch>
                      <Route path='/home' component={HomeContainerComponent} />
                  <Route path='/componentOne' component={componentOne} />               
                  <Route path='/componentTwo' component={componentTwo} />
                  <Redirect to="/home"/>
                </Switch>
                </main>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default PrimaryLayout;
```

---

***I hope my approach was helpful to you and if you have any further questions, please let me know. I'll answer them ASAP***

Comment: Hi @Bigga_HD, Thanks for your answer. Learning from your code, My code is now passing history as props and i am also thinking of using state to keep track of routes. I was wondering why you are using componentWillReceivepRrops()  methods in PrimaryLayoutComponent.js. ComponentWillMount() Method updates the state based on props change.

Comment: @Jiah827 - `componentWillMount` is called once at first render. `componentWillReceiveProps` is called for subsequent renders. The problem is I don't know for sure if the prop will be initialized by the time the first render is called. (The prop depends on asynchronous data). So - I can't put the code in componentWillMount. But if I put it in componentWillReceiveProps and then change something higher up the component chain so that the data is fulfilled synchronously now my code in componentWillReceiveProps is never run.

Comment: That's just how I usually used to deal with async data and HOC. If `componentWillMount` works for your situation, great, use that one only :) 

If my code was of any help, please consider at least an upvote. Thanks.

But I wouldn't worry about, `componentWillReceiveProps` is deprecated and will be removed in the next major version. - > React 17 ... for more info, I would suggest reading this post. 

https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html

Comment: I see. Thank you Bigga_HD !! I've already upvoted your answer but apparently it doesn't change publicly displayed post score since i don't have enough reputation yet :/

Comment: Don't worry about it. I was kinda joking. I'm just glad it was helpful ;)